# I need my Section header on same page as my image, i've tried different varitions of htbp added and took out float packages. here is what i have in

Tags: sectioning

```
\section [Conduit Assemblies]{\centering Conduit Assemblies}


    \begin{figure} [htbp]
\renewcommand\thefigure{19} % Make this figure 19
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.65]{figure19}
    \caption{Conduit Elbow Assemblies}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Just omit floating environment `figure` ...

Comment: how do i omit Figure?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\section [Conduit Assemblies]{\centering Conduit Assemblies}


    \begin{figure}[H]
\renewcommand\thefigure{19} % Make this figure 19
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.65]{figure19}
    \caption{Conduit Elbow Assemblies}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: it put the chapter at the bottom of the page below the image, even though the chapter is written in latex before image